# Given the following linq queries, which one is 'more performant'?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, parallel-processing

Given the following `for each` statement that has some linq in it, I need to iterate through the list as `Distinct`. So I have a number of places I can add the `Distict()` statement.

Can someone please explain which solution I should use and why? I'm very new to using `AsParallel()` so I'm not sure which solution to go with..

#### Existing Code (which is missing and needs the `Distinct()`)

```
foreach (var phrase in (something != null 
    ? ListOne.AsParallel() 
    : ListTwo.AsParallel()))
{
 ... // irrelevant for this question 
}
```

#### Option 1: Distincting the entire result.

```
foreach (var phrase in (something != null 
    ? ListOne.AsParallel() 
    : ListTwo.AsParallel()).Distinct())
{
 ... // irrelevant for this question 
}
```

I feel that this would return too much info back (initially).

#### Option 2: Distinct each list, before Parallel

```
foreach (var phrase in (something != null 
    ? ListOne.Distinct().AsParallel() 
    : ListTwo.Distinct().AsParallel()))
{
 ... // irrelevant for this question 
}
```

#### Option 3: Distinct each list, after the Parallel

```
foreach (var phrase in (something != null 
    ? ListOne.AsParallel().Distinct() 
    : ListTwo.AsParallel().Distinct() ))
{
 ... // irrelevant for this question 
}
```

Yes - I could create my own test code with stopwatches, etc.. but I'm not so much after the metrics, but more the theory (as to what I should do .. because of XXXXX).

** Before this turns into a subjective question and get closed down, please consider your answers.
** Secondly, I understand the perf here is tiny .. so just to iterate, I'm not so much worried about the -actual- perf difference, but the theoretical difference.

Comment: Side note: I don't believe `foreach` knows about ParallelQuery and will use regular `IEnumerable` out of it (no parallel execution)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1 and 3 will result in the same execution paths. In both cases `Distinct` is called on the result of `AsParallel`. This means that the question really boils down to whether it is better to call Distinct before or after the `AsParallel()`.

Based on the actual implementation of [`ParallelEnumerable.Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383943.aspx) which simply uses the non-parallel `Enumerable.Distinct` I would say that it makes no difference at all in your case, because you don't actually have a query here. You are just distincting an existing list. You probably shouldn't be using `AsParallel` here at all.

In case you actually do have a query, it is potentially better to call `Distinct` last, because it won't be executed in parallel and be potentially faster if executed on a smaller set - which has been filtered down in parallel. But this part of the answer needs actual benchmarking to be verified.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the type of answer i was after :) Question: So the `AsParallel()` doesn't break up all the list items in parallel? For example, if i had 10 items in the list, would each item will be retrieved synchronously? Or a few items at the same time (parallel) ?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: What do you mean by "retrieved"? If you have a list, the items are already there.

Comment: the `foreach` loop 'retrieves' each item out of the collection, then does something with it. I thought the `.AsParallel()` was saying to the `for each` .. don't get these one by one, but in parallel (either 2 or 3 at a time, etc) .. because the result of the inner scope is independent from each 'item'. (If that made any more sense).

Comment: @Pure.Krome: Ah, that's what you mean. No, that's not happening. `AsParallel` will just make the query that comes after it run in parallel. In your case there is no query, so no benefit in or reason for calling `AsParallel`. It seems as if you are actually looking for [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx).